# DevExpress Datagrid Master-Detail Multiple List<type> as a Datasource - Guidance

Tags: c#, list, devexpress

My program gets two lists of custom types. The first list is the master and contain a schedule, the second list is the detail and contains the actions taken against the master list.

I am trying to apply these binding lists to a DevExpress Grid Control in a Windows Form with the above mentioned relationship (Master-detail), but I am stumped by how to do this. The examples and walk-troughs I have read use ADO datasets.

I imagine I would have to take the two lists and program a relationship in some kind of dataset file and link this to the grid, but I must admit I haven't a clue. Any guidance welcome.

Thanks :)

P.S. I should mention, I have successfully bound the master view to a list, but my trouble comes when I try to bind the detail view to a data source. It seems to me that the data source will only accept one binding source and the binding source will only accept one binding list.
[image: Ref comment below]

Answer (score 2):

The GridControl is smart enough to detect a master-detail relation based directly on data-type:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = new List<Blog> { 
    new Blog { 
        Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet",
        Posts = new List<Post>{
            new Post() { Title = "The First" },
            new Post() { Title = "The Second" }
        } 
    }
};
```

[image]
The relation is defined onto the `Blog` class level via List-property:

```
public class Blog {
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; } // <<<
}
public class Post {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Let me try it out and get back to you on this post :)

Comment: ...but I should say I am experiencing one little problem with it. I have ten master records, and one of those records has a detail record. When the gridcontrol's data source is set, I see ten master records and a detail record nested under the correct master file.

That said, I don't see any master records values, but I do see detail records values. I have checked the property names match what the gridview expects and they do.

If you have any guidance on this, I would be most appreciative. I'll attach an image to the main post as "Ref comment below".

Comment: Hold the press! I got it. I had to prefix the field name with a reference to the type that had the property i.e. "Plan.PlanIdentity". Again, thanks for your help and time. :)